# get data at runtime

Tags: excel, vba

I have to capture sheet row into a 2d array. I am using the following code

Code :

```
Sub multiarr()

    Dim str As String      'String Which i am looking for
    Dim result() As String 'Stores Splitted Substring
    Dim r As Integer       ' Row Counter of 2d array
    Dim c As Integer       ' Column Counter of 2d Array
    Dim valarr() As String ' Initial Declaration of Array

    'Row and Column Initialization
    r = 0
    c = 0

    'Calculate Last Row and Last Column of Sheet
    mylr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lcol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    'Initialize the Array according to Sheet Dimentions
    ReDim valarr(mylr - 2, lcol - 1) 'Declare Array to be of size of Sheet

    str = "M1" ' -> This i am interested in.Only these records will be populated

    For y = 0 To UBound(valarr) 'iterate through rows of array
        For x = 2 To mylr           'iterate through rows of sheet
            result = Split(Cells(x, 1), "@") ' Split the Record
            If result(0) = str Then     'Check for the Condition
                'Array Filling Logic
                For c = 1 To lcol
                    ' C-1 because column index starts from 0
                    valarr(y, c - 1) = Cells(x, c)
                Next c
            End If
        Next x
    Next y

End Sub
```

But this code is incorrectly filling. What is the problem?

Please refer sample image of worksheet

[image: img1]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Wouldn't it better to use auto filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the bellow, hope it helps

```
Sub multiarr()

    Dim str As String      'String Which i am looking for
    Dim result() As String 'Stores Splitted Substring
    Dim r As Integer       ' Row Counter of 2d array
    Dim c As Integer       ' Column Counter of 2d Array
    Dim valarr() As String ' Initial Declaration of Array
    Dim mylr As Long, lcol As Long  'lastrow / lastcol

    'I recommend declaring the workbook/worksheet and declaring the ranges accordingly
    'Without doing so, any range refence bellow is explicit to the ActiveSheet

    Dim arrValues As Variant
    Dim cnt As Long, cnt2 As Long

    'Row and Column Initialization
    r = 1
    c = 1

    'Calculate Last Row and Last Column of Sheet
    mylr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    lcol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column

    arrValues = Range(Cells(r, c), Cells(mylr, lcol))

    str = "M1" ' -> This i am interested in.Only these records will be populated

    For y = LBound(arrValues) To UBound(arrValues)  'Iterate through values
        If Left(arrValues(y, 1), 2) = str Then      'Check if the correct value exists
            cnt = cnt + 1                           'Count the number of occurences
        End If
    Next y

    'Initialize the Array according to Results Dimentions
    ReDim valarr(1 To cnt, 1 To lcol) 'Declare Array to be of size of Sheet

    cnt2 = 1                                        'Start at one to match the array of the values, but... feel free to change
    For y = LBound(arrValues) To UBound(arrValues)  'Iterate through array rows
        If Left(arrValues(y, 1), 2) = str Then      'Check if the correct value exists
            For z = LBound(arrValues, 2) To UBound(arrValues, 2)    'Iterate through array columns
                valarr(cnt2, z) = arrValues(y, z)                   'Add to the arr only correct values
            Next z
        cnt2 = cnt2 + 1                                             'If value find, we increase the counter
        End If
    Next y

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**this answer only addresses the issue of getting a range into a 2-D array, not the processing of the elements.**

This code is a pretty efficient method:

```
Sub multiarr()
    Dim str As String 'String Which i am looking for
    Dim result() As String 'Stores Splitted Substring
    Dim r As Integer ' Row Counter of 2d array
    Dim c As Integer ' Column Counter of 2d Array
    Dim valarr()

    valarr = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    MsgBox LBound(valarr, 1) & "-" & UBound(valarr, 1) & vbCrLf & LBound(valarr, 2) & "-" & UBound(valarr, 2)
End Sub
```

[image]

If you can't adapt the approach to your needs, ignore this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use auto filter (see comments in code):

```
Sub multiarr()

    Dim rng As Range, rngData As Range, rngFilter As Range

    '// Full range
    Set rng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    '// Range without a header
    With rng
        Set rngData = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1)
    End With
    rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="M1*"
    '// Error handling in case if no rows will be filtered
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngFilter = rngData.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If Err = 0 Then
        '// Do something with your range.
        '// Do not forget to use Areas,
        '// since rngFilter can be non-contiguous:
        '// Dim cell As Range, rngRow As Range, rngArea As Range
        '// For Each rngArea in rngFilter.Areas
        '//     For Each cell in rngArea
        '//     'Or For Each rngRow in rngArea.Rows
        '//         // Do something...
        '//     Next
        '// Next
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```